# URL Rewrite seems to be functioning like a URL Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the rewrite section of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^komarketingassociates\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.komarketingassociates.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^industry-news/.*[$]([0-9]+)\.htm$ http://www.komarketingassociates.com/industry-news/article.php?articleid=$1 [L]
```

The last rewrite rule is meant to process requests for our repository of news articles.  Until maybe a week ago it was working perfectly translating the SEO friendly link titles like this one, companies-are-becoming-more-accustomed-to-leveraging-social-media$715.htm into the proper format to retrieve them from the database.  Recently, however, without any changes being made to the .htaccess file (to my knowledge) the links now seem to use this redirect to article.php?articleid=715 rather than doing it server side.  The links on the site are still the seo friendly urls, but now it seems as if you are being redirected to the article template page.

We are using GoDaddy to host our site.  PHP version 5. I am completely stumped as to how this is happening and how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
-Bill

Comment: Have you asked godaddy if they've changed their configuration? It sounds like you are fetching external webpages automatically, and they may have disabled that.

Answer (score 1):

`P`roxy flag. (P)

Warning, will mess with IPs. Every single IP will look like it's your servers. However, mod_rewrite sets the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` when you use `P`, so you can extract (I'd recommend validating the IP as being real as well before trying to use it in any SQL) and use the IP address still.